# Checkintime not coming correctly because of NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called times and i am using mssql database

```
id  |   checkintime             |           checkouttime    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
1   |   2016-06-30 07:00:00.000 |           NULL            |   
1   |   NULL                    |   2016-06-30 18:00:00.000 |   
1   |   2016-07-01 07:00:00.000 |           NULL            |   
1   |   NULL                    |   2016-07-01 18:00:00.000 |   
2   |   NULL                    |   2016-07-01 18:00:00.000 |
```

I am expecting the output like

```
id  |   checkintime     |           checkouttime    |
-----------------------------------------------------
2   |   NULL            |   2016-07-01 18:00:00.000 |
```

When I am running this query:

```
select * from times
where checkintime is null
and CheckOutTime 
     between convert(varchar(10),getdate()-1,120) 
           and convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)
```

I am getting the output like:

```
id  |   checkintime     |           checkouttime    |
----------------------------------------------------
1   |   NULL            |   2016-07-01 18:00:00.000 |   
2   |   NULL            |   2016-07-01 18:00:00.000 |
```

Than i modified my query to something like this

```
select * from times
where checkintime is null
and CheckOutTime 
        between convert(varchar(10),getdate()-1,120) 
               and convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)
and not exists
(select * from times 
  where 1=1
    and ( checkintime 
              between convert(varchar(10),getdate()-1,120) 
              and convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120) 
           or CheckInTime is null
         )
)
```

But it is giving me blank, I am not sure what is wrong in this

Comment: Can you explain a little more why you want to return id=2 but not id=1 for 7/1?  Not sure I'm really understanding the requirements.

Comment: bcoz id=1 already have a checkin on 1st (1 | 2016-07-01 07:00:00.000 | NULL |)

Comment: as i see , the expression and not exists (select * from times where 1=1 and ( checkintime between convert(varchar(10),getdate()-1,120) and convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120) or CheckInTime is null ))and not exists (select * from times where 1=1 and ( checkintime between convert(varchar(10),getdate()-1,120) and convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120) or CheckInTime is null )) always return false for all row then you get blank is correct . please check this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `checkouttime` times that don't have a matching `checkintime`.  You can calculate a cumulative count of each and then take rows where the cumulative for `checkouttime` is greater than the cumulative for `checkintime`.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(checkintime) over (partition by id order by coalesce(checkintime, checkouttime)) as cnt_in,
             count(checkouttime) over (partition by id order by coalesce(checkouttime, checkintime)) as cnt_out
      from times t
     ) t
where checkouttime is not null and cnt_out > cnt_in;
```

EDIT:

SQL Server 2008 doesn't support cumulative counts, but you can do:

```
      select t.*
      from times t outer apply
           (select count(t2.checkintime) as cnt
            from times t2
            where t2.id = t.id and
                  coalesce(t2.checkintime, t2.checkouttime) <= coalesce(t.checkintime, t.checkouttime)
           ) ins outer apply
           (select count(t2.checkouttime) as cnt
            from times t2
            where t2.id = t.id and
                  coalesce(t2.checkouttime, t2.checkintime) <= coalesce(t.checkouttime, t.checkintime)
           ) outs
where t.checkouttime is not null and outs.cnt > ins.cnt;
```

Comment: it is giving me incorrect syntax near order and I am using sqlsever2008

Comment: it is still giving me an error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'coalesce'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'coalesce'.

Comment: still an error: -      Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The multi-part identifier "ct2.heckintime" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The multi-part identifier "ct2.heckintime" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
The multi-part identifier "ct2.heckouttime" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
The multi-part identifier "ct2.heckouttime" could not be bound.

Comment: I did corrected the checkin and checout time before also and still its giving an error

Comment: can we make a change in a code where it start the checintime and checouttime count for  1 day. I mean to say it should count the checkintime and checkouttime for today only. But in my caseit is caluclating from 1st entry in DB